# heroku type "geometry" does not exist after pg:reset

Tags: python, django, heroku, geodjango

So I did a pg:reset on my heroku db but now when I try to run the migrations with 'heroku run python manage.py migrate' I get the error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "geometry" does not exist`
i've tried going into console and running `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` but it says `ERROR:  extension "postgis" already exists`